# Apply quaternion on an object, and where it look at?

Tags: opengl, 3d, quaternions, glm-math

<s>I know I may apply quaternion on an up vector (0,1,0), then the result is the object's orentation.</s>

I mean we could get the object's orentation by applying quaternion on an up vector (0,1,0). 
But, how could I get the roll (or spin) on the orentation of the object ?

I prefer a solution using glm = = since I'm developing on opengl = =...

Comment: What do you mean by "then the result is the object's orientation"? Applying a quaternion to the up-vector will give you the up-vector of the model after the transformation. This should in general also include roll movement (since this is a rotation around the local x-axis).

Comment: @BDL For example, applying a rotation which axis is (0,1,0) and angle is pi/2, the orentation vector is still (0,1,0) and the roll on the orentation is pi/2, but there is no roll information from the orentation vector. That roll value is what I want.

Comment: I guess the roll is exactly rotation angle, but I'm not sure = =

Comment: The change in roll is the rotation angle that you used to calculate the quaternion. If you're looking for the roll (rather than change in roll) then you can apply the same quaternion rotation to (0, 0, 1), for instance.